how do I display videos from Firebase in a Kivy app?
I have problem of displaying more than one video with thumbnails in the Kivy app, I don't know if it is possible display videos in a layout from Firebase without having downloaded the videos from Firebase.
if any one can help me and direct, please, I need your help.
I tried the process with pyrebase, python-firebase sdk, even with requests but still am failing out.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
